# Killing thousands of extraneous processes on Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, gunicorn

I'm using gunicorn 19.7.1 appserver with nginx reverse proxy for a Django project (Ubuntu 14.04 machine).

`ps aux | grep gunicorn | grep -v grep | wc -l` yields **3043** at the moment.

Whereas in `/etc/init/gunicorn.conf`, I've always had `-w 33`. Yet these extra workers persist even if I do `sudo service gunicorn stop` and `sudo service gunicorn start`.

How do I kill the extraneous workers?

---

**What I've tried:**

`sudo service gunicorn stop` and `sudo service gunicorn start` hasn't worked.

Next, I've been recommended two ways to kill extraneous workers. I tried them - they were unsuccessful too. Basically when I try them, nothing happens.

Here's the first way:

1) Get gunicorn `pid` via `sudo service gunicorn status`

2) Save all 'desired' workers that aren't to be killed:

```
echo 123 > desired_workers
pgrep -P 123 >> desired_workers
```

3) Now get all gunicorn workers globally:

```
pgrep gunicorn > all_workers
```

4) Lastly, simply do:

```
cat desired_workers all_workers | sort | uniq -u | xargs kill
```

The above didn't work. Likewise doing `cat desired_workers all_workers | sort | uniq -u | xargs sudo kill` didn't work either. Nor trying this out as `root`.

Next, I simply tried `pkill gunicorn` and `sudo pkill gunicorn`. Nothing happened in either case. What else can I do here?

---

**How were extraneous gunicorn workers created?**

The worker count of `33` has always been properly configured on my busy production system.

However a few hours ago, I was trying python's multiprocessing on the server and things went south. Gunicorn workers ate up all the memory and took out the resident redis instances as well.

I reverted the change and have managed to get everything back online, except the memory hasn't been released and I've had to cope with these legacy gunicorn workers. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try sending a different signal with kill. The default is `TERM`, you could try `INT` and if that doesn't work `KILL`, for e.g

```
cat desired_workers all_workers | sort | uniq -u | xargs kill -INT
```

> How were extraneous gunicorn workers created?

Something you did whilst

> I was trying python's multiprocessing on the server and things went south.

You really should not do this kind of research on your production systems. Test systems are easy to spin up and const much less than the time you have spent (not) fixing things.

Comment: Yea I did set it up locally, but I didn't simulate the traffic profile my production system gets. Moreover, it was my first foray into multiprocessing, I was in a "what's the worst that can happen" mode. And so here we are. Major bummer.

Comment: Did this solve the issue with the processes ?